# Using a junction table in a many to many relationship

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am learning EF Core.  Say I have a many to many relationship with a junction table like this:

```
public class PostTag
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public Post Post { get; set; }

    public int TagId { get; set; }
    public Tag Tag { get; set; }
}
```

Say I wanted to perform a database insert.

```
var post = new Post { Id=Guid.NewGuid(), Description="Test Post" };
var tag = new Tag { Id=Guid.NewGuid(), Description="Test Text"  };
var PostTag = new PostTag { Post=post; Tag=tag; PostId=Post.Id, TagId=Tag.Id};
context.Add(PostTag);
```

This one insert appears to:

```
1) Insert a post.
2) Insert a Tag
3) Insert a PostTag
```

Q1) Why does PostTag contain PostId and TagId? This information is contained in Post and Tag (also two fields in PostTag).  It appears that these fields are duplicated.

Q2) Does adding a PostTag also add the Post and the Tag?

Answer (score 0):

> Why does PostTag contain PostId and TagId? This information is contained in Post and Tag (also two fields in PostTag). It appears that these fields are duplicated.

As you know, the `PostTag.PostId` is a foreign key that references the `Post.Id`, and the `PostTag.TagId` is a foreign key which references the `Tag.Id`. The `PostTag.PostId` called `Foreign Key Property` and `PostTag.Post` is `Navigation Property`.

Actually, if you don't have a foreign key property for navigation property explicitly, the `EF Core` will also work as expected. In that case, two shadow foreign key properties of `PostId` and `TagId` will be introduced for you automatically. It is called [`Shadow Properties`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/shadow-properties).

> Shadow properties can be created by convention when a relationship is discovered but no foreign key property is found in the dependent entity class. In this case, a shadow foreign key property will be introduced. The shadow foreign key property will be named **`<navigation property name><principal key property name>`** (the navigation on the dependent entity, which points to the principal entity, is used for the naming). If the principal key property name includes the name of the navigation property, then the name will just be **`<principal key property name>`**. If there is no navigation property on the dependent entity, then the principal type name is used in its place.

1. **Although these foreign key can be inferred by the `PostTag.Post.Id` and `PostTag.Tag.Id` respectively, they're not duplicated**.

   Let's say we have an existing database where the foreign keys are named as `fk_post_id` and `fk_tag_id`, and you want to rename the foreign key property `PostId` to `MyPostId`, we cannot omit the `PostId` and `TagId` properties :

   ```
   public class PostTag
   {
       [Column("fk_post_id")]
       public Guid MyPostId { get; set; }
       [ForeignKey("MyPostId")]
       public Post Post { get; set; }


       [Column("fk_tag_id")]
       public Guid TagId { get; set; }
       public Tag Tag { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. **It is recommended to have a foreign key property defined in the dependent entity class for the navigation property**

> Does adding a PostTag also add the Post and the Tag?

Your code inserts a post and tag automatically for you because it knows that you need to create a brand new post and a brand new tag. But that's not always that case. It depends on the tracking state and the entity itself.

If you execute the following code :

```
    var tagTracked = this._dbContext.Tag.FirstOrDefault();
    var post = new Post { Id=Guid.NewGuid(), Description="Test Post3" };
    var PostTag = new PostTag { 
        Post=post, 
        Tag=tagTracked, 
        MyPostId= post.Id, 
        TagId= tagTracked.Id,
    };
    this._dbContext.Add(PostTag);
    this._dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

The `tagTracked` will not be inserted . If you want to insert a new tag record , you need to make the `tag` untracked :

```
    var tagTracked = this._dbContext.Tag.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault();
    tagTracked.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
    var post = new Post { Id=Guid.NewGuid(), Description="Test Post3" };
    var PostTag = new PostTag { 
        Post=post, 
        Tag=tagTracked, 
        MyPostId= post.Id, 
        TagId= tagTracked.Id,
    };
    this._dbContext.Add(PostTag);
    this._dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Again, it will insert a new tag record in the database. For more information, refer [docs here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/disconnected-entities)

Comment: Thanks.  If you have a many to many relationship then I believe you have to have a junction entity (Post-war in this case).  This seems to be a significant downside of ef core.  Is that right? I have seen the github article - I just want to make sure it is still true after many years.

Comment: @w0051977 You're right.  According to [the official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships#many-to-many) ,  for the time being,  EF Core will not automatically take care of Many-to-Many relationship without a junction entity for us .